# Пиктограмма пакета в виде жука в Oracle Toad

Tags: oracle

Что означает, если в клиенте Оракла Тоад пиктограмма пакета не в виде жука, а как белый лист?

Answer (score 1):

Это означает, что пакет откомпилирован без режима отладки. Будет выполняться немного быстрее. Чтобы включить отладку, нужно перекомпилировать.